# Setting color to a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a dynamic array and have the following code, i am trying to add a color to the "name" of the array. Everything else works perfectly apart from **"fontcolor("red")"** .

```
if (val < 0) {
    myArray.push({
            "name" : myVariable.fontcolor("red"),
            "size" : -10
    });
} else {
    myArray.push({
            "name" : myVariable,
            "size" : 5
    });
}
```

I end up with the following when displayed on thet HTML page:

```
<font color="red">Strong rubber(minus)</font>
```

I am actualy drawing a chart and I am using the d3.js to draw the charts, my code that draws up "Dog Toys". myVariable has the value "myVariable"

```
 <g style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; " transform="translate(0,0)"> 
  <text x="-6" y="10" dy=".50em" text-anchor="end">Dog Toys</text> 
  <rect width="478.57142857142867" height="20" style="fill: #4682b4; "></rect> 
 </g>
```

Any idea how i could set a color to text, when its displayed on the web page?

Comment: can you post the code that translates the array into HTML?

Comment: FYI, the `<font>` tag and the `color` attribute are deprecated. Use css instead.

Comment: @jbabey - I am actualy drawing a chart and I am using the d3.js to draw the charts, my code that draws up "Dog Toys"

<g style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; " transform="translate(0,0)">
<text x="-6" y="10" dy=".50em" text-anchor="end">Dog Toys</text>
<rect width="478.57142857142867" height="20" style="fill: #4682b4; "></rect>
</g>

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with the d3.js library. I assume there is a style, or color property you can assign somehow, but I wouldn't know that. Good luck with your search.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
myVariable.style.color = "Red"
```

Comment: Did not work, basically myVariable is a string that has a value derived from the database. I get this error"Cannot set property 'color' of undefined "

Comment: What does the string look like? From the looks of your code, you're trying to set the CSS value "color" to red on the myVariable object. This will indeed not work on a simple string.

Comment: The string returns "Dog Toys" , i need to display it in red when size is less than 0

Comment: Can you post some more code then? Like jbabey commented on your OP: Can you post the code that translates the array into HTML?

Comment: I am actualy drawing a chart and I am using the d3.js to draw the charts, my code that draws up "Dog Toys"
<g style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; " transform="translate(0,0)">
<text x="-6" y="10" dy=".50em" text-anchor="end">Dog Toys</text>
<rect width="478.57142857142867" height="20" style="fill: #4682b4; "></rect>
</g>

Comment: Can you edit your OP and provide this extra information? This will help other readers of your question and will allow for a more readable formatting of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
myVariable.style.color = "red";
```